# How to use mysql source command with force option

Tags: mysql

My dump file is 32GB and I can't re-dump again, In dump file, some errors exist, I should to use SOURCE command, Does SOURCE command have any force option? Like:

```
mysql -u user --force -p db < /path/dump.sql
```

for example any option like this:

```
mysql> SOURCE **-f** /path/dump.sql
```

Comment: What's the reason you can't redump it? Do you not have access to the db anymore or would it take too long and block the site? What kind of errors do you have in that file?

Comment: Re-dump take too long time, errors like this: 
ERROR 1231 (42000) at line 428 in file: '/path/dump.sql': Variable 'time_zone' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
ERROR 1231 (42000) at line 430 in file: '/path/dump.sql': Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
ERROR 1231 (42000) at line 431 in file: '/path/dump.sql': Variable 'foreign_key_checks' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
ERROR 1231 (42000) at line 432 in file: '/path/dump.sql': Variable 'unique_checks' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'

Comment: You have damaged this dump file, and it would not be advisable to try to force restoring it.  Did you try to modify it or split it into multiple files, or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments:
It seams like the issue is in the structure of the database you try to import the data to.
You have some fields in your file set to `NULL` and in the db you try to import to those fields are marked as `NOT NULL`. I'd suggest you fix the table structure of the target db.

Take a look at the `-d` option of `mysqldump` with it, you can dump only the structure of the db, which should be extremely fast.

For dumping not to look the db, you can use `--lock-tables=false` and  if your using InnoDB you can use `--single-transaction` too on the `mysqldump` command

Comment: I don't know what is 'time_zone' Variable, time_zone is not field, I don't know mysqldump why creats this variables.

Comment: Then it's probably a seting of the mysql server. Since the server can handle dates and time it probably has to have a time zone in it's config. If thats a line in the dump at the start of your dump you can simply ignore it and comment it out. Use a editir that doesn't load the whole file for this though!

Comment: Can you tell me which editor doesn't load whole file?

Comment: *"If thats a line in the dump at the start of your dump you can simply ignore it and comment it out."*  Unsafe advice.   A file created by `mysqldump` would not throw these errors unless the file has been improperly handled or manipulated, and this specific error suggests that previous lines have been tampered with or removed when they should not have been.  It's fundamentally a corrupt backup and there's no way to know what else has been broken -- it can't be trusted.

Comment: Dump files manipulate `@@time_zone` and other variables on the server where they are being restored so that the data is restored properly.  Without the changes to `@@time_zone`, timestamps will not restore correctly.  Without changes to `@@foreign_key_checks`, tables with foreign keys will either not create at all or will fail to load.  These particular errors are occurring the *second* (or some subsequent) time the variable is touched, which suggests the first touch (which is actually a read) has been lost from the file, which is a bad sign of the trustworthiness of the file.